# How to call Python function in Java

Tags: java, python, spring

This is my Python code:

```
class myPythonClass:
    def table(nb):
        i = 0
        while i < 10: 
            print(i + 1, "*", nb, "=", (i + 1) * nb)
            i += 1
```

I need to know how to call it using PythonInterpreter.

Comment: Just search for "java systemcall"; and seriously: I guess the above python code simply prints out some characters. Why on earth do you want to call a python interpreter for that? What prevents you from turning those few lines into java code?

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your "question" is not clear. What did you try so far?

Comment: When you say "call using PythonInterpreter", do you mean as a subprocess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to create a child process and capture its standard output. Here's an example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class CallPython {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "/path/to/your/script.py", "10");
        Process p = pb.start();

        char[] readBuffer = new char[1000];
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        while (true) {
            int n = br.read(readBuffer);
            if (n <= 0)
                break;
            System.out.print(new String(readBuffer, 0, n));
        }
    }
}
```

Your Python script will also need modifications so that it can call the function, which should actually be a static method, a method of the class, or simply be a stand alone function. The script also needs a value for `nb` so that it can be passed to the function - use `sys.argv` for that. So e.g. as a static method:

```
import sys

class myPythonClass:
    @staticmethod
    def table(nb):
        i = 0
        while i < 10: 
            print(i + 1, "*", nb, "=", (i + 1) * nb)
            i += 1 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myPythonClass.table(int(sys.argv[1]))
```